Is my pivot point mojave dirt jumper compatible with bmx cranks
Is my pivot point mojave dirt jumper compatible with bmx cranks if the cranks work on a 73mm bottom bracket shell?  Specifically I want to use Eclat tibia cranks.



Yes, you can. You need what is called a Euro BottomBracket in the BMX world for the 19mm spindle.
The spindle length you need will be determined partly by the bottom bracket you choose and partly by the chainline you are trying to achieve. Perhaps buy and fit the BB first so you can measure up for what you need.
https://thebmxdude.com/bmx-bottom-bracket-types/
link gives general details about bmx bb types.
